# Why is easy to clone cats but it's hard to clone dogs?

Tags: cloning

According to this article, [Here is why we're not cloning humans](http://www.businessinsider.com/can-you-clone-a-human-2016-7)
there are species who are easy to clone and other who are hard to clone. Cats and mices would be in the easy to clone set , and dogs and humans would be in the hard/very hard to clone set. Why is this so? Why is easy to clone cats but it's hard to clone dogs?

Comment: If you have enough money, you can have your dog cloned.

Comment: Out of date. Primates have now been cloned.

Comment: But there it doesnt say they havent been cloned. They say it's hard. I have to assume this is confidential information and nobody knows why